# Using data from a PHP array in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm making a change to the way a site works and trying to find a solution that requires as little re-writing as possible.

At the moment, I have a file (myFile.php) which loads (using Wordpress) into a page. It uses a PHP array for outputting data. The PHP array is `$property_list_featured_search` and the content looks something like this:

```
<?php 
    foreach($property_list_featured_search as $individual_property){
?>
    <span><?php echo $individual_property['info']['status'] ?></span>
<?php
    }
?>
```

So in my small example, it's outputting data from `$property_list_featured_search` and this works OK.

My problem is that I now want to load the HTML&PHP above using jQuery AJAX. When a user clicks a button, it loads the HTML (which is stored in a file, called `myFile.php` into a div on the page:

```
function loadView(view){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'path/to/file/property-search/myFile.php',
            data: property_data,
            success: function(result)
            {
                $("#search-page-content").html(result);
        });
    }
```

In the case above, `property_data` is the `$property_list_featured_search` data localized using Wordpress so that the file can access it. I have tested it and can confirm that the file loaded in with AJAX is able to see the data. My problem is that I now have a file with PHP `echo` everywhere and the data in `JSON` format.

Is it possible to still use this data in this way? I'm guessing because the data is `JSON` that it's not possible to use `echo $data[key]` at all like it was in the original file?

What's the best way to output all the data in the `JSON` file on the page?

Comment: Have you tried using `json_encode()` ? If that works then maybe you don't need `echo` at all.

Comment: What part is JSON? `property_data` on page one `data`? I don't get what you are saying to be honest. You said `$property_list_featured_search` (array) is being sent to `path/to/file/property-search/property-search-view.php` via `property_data`?

Comment: And where does `myFile.php` come in to play? I don't see that except in your description.

Comment: @Rasclatt myFile.php edited to clarify. `property_data` is JSON. Yes. `$property_list_featured_search` is a PHP array. It's localized using Wordpress `localize_script` as `property_data`. This is then passed in the AJAX.

Comment: Ok so in `myFile.php` what do you get there from the post? Don't get all your data as a post? Like it should be `$_POST[0]['info']['status']` (with more keys of course)

Comment: @Rasclatt in myFile.php by debugging and console logging `property_data` I can see that I have the data as JSON. But the whole file uses PHP to output, so I wanted to know if it's possible to still use the PHP syntax or if I have to rewrite the entire file using Javascript to output, which seems messy.

Comment: @Rasclatt using $_POST[0] I get nothing. Empty. Nothing outputs except the HTML in myFile.php

Comment: So if you do `print_r($_POST);` is it empty?

Comment: Have you tried using json_decode on property_data. This will convert your data into a php array

Comment: What you are asking is doable, by the way, in many different ways. Just need to know what exactly `myFile.php` is actually receiving from the Ajax

Comment: @Rasclatt I get `Array ( [undefined] => )`

Comment: @DenisKumbaradzi how do I do that?

Comment: But inside if you do `console.log(property_data);` it shows the javascript data object (json)?

Comment: @Rasclatt If I do that, I can see the data in console: http://grab.by/Sidi

Comment: As the others have mentioned, if you haven't already encoded it somewhere, it will not work `var property_data  = <?php echo json_encode($property_list_featured_search); ?>;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121666/discussion-between-user1486133-and-rasclatt).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this: 
When u get your data:

```
  $checked = $_POST['property_data'];
  $checked = array('first' => $checked[0], 'second' => $checked[1], 'third' => $checked[2], 'forth' => $checked[3]);
```

Then you can echo it like this:

```
$checked['first'], $checked['second'] and so on.
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Did you maybe try, after u get it: $array = json_decode($propertydata) ?